# vueJS router: Update page title from component data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm running VueJS with vue router installed, the titles are currently working OK except from one detail.

In the example below all pages work OK, however if I use the `/user/:user_id` route to display a specific user I don't know how to show the username in the title, e.g: `'Cool Page - [USER_NAME]'`.

This username is obtained in the Component from the database after the component uses the `:user_id` to retrieve that users data from Vuex.

How can I do this?

```
routes: [
  {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {'title': "Cool Page",
        'metaTags': metaTags},
    },
    {
      path: '/users',
      name: 'users',
      component: Users,
      meta: {'title': "CoolPage - Users",
        metaTags: metaTags},
    },
     {
      path: '/user/:user_id',
      name: 'user',
      component: User,
      meta: {'title': "Cool Page - Some User",
        metaTags: metaTags },
...
```

```
const DEFAULT_TITLE = 'Coolpage.com';
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title || DEFAULT_TITLE;
});
```

In my Component:
I have a computed property to use the vuex getter, and a data variable for the prop, like this:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allUsers','getUserById', 'getUserStoreStatus']),
    user: function () {
      var u = this.getUserById(this.user_id);
      if(u){ return u; }
      else{ return {}; }
    },
},
data(){
    return {
      user_id: this.$route.params.user_id,
    }
 }
...
```

Comment: Just update the title after you got the data in your component?

Comment: @ZedHome Something like `window.document.title = "CoolPage - "+this.user.name;`
   in the created()? Would changing the title at that point the lifecycle hurt SEO?

Comment: @Nelo can you post how you are fetching that data from your Vuex store?

Comment: @maxshuty I added the fetching to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply `import` your store where you are getting the user info, like this:

```
import store from '../store';
```

Then you will do something like this (I haven't seen your store code so you'll have to alter this bit to fit your needs):

```
const DEFAULT_TITLE = 'Coolpage.com';
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    const userInfo = store.getters['getUserInfo'];
    // This could be cleaned up a bit, but you get the point...
    document.title = to.name === 'user' ? 
        `Cool Page - ${userInfo.username}` : 
        to.meta.title || DEFAULT_TITLE;
});
```

Comment: This seems to work in my dev sever, I didn't know I could use the store in my router.js file. I'll post my code to the question above and let you know once I run it on staging.